# Excel VBA - Copy Paste Range in column if Date matches

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My macro is used to copy/paste live data to overwrite an old budget.

**Essentially I want to do the following:**

If the date in `T6` = date in `Range(G6:R6)` then copy `Range(T10:T30)` to `Range(?10:?30)`, where `?` is the column of the cell that matched the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match what you're asking for. In the future, you should share the code that you've attempted so far.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("G6:R6")
    If cell.value = Range("T6").value Then
        Range(Cells(10, cell.Column), Cells(30, cell.Column)).value = Range("T10:T30").value
    End If
Next cell
```